# How to sort an array based document and return only the first element of the result

Tags: mongodb

I am storing document  in format of an array as shown below in mongodb .

```
{
    "plans": [
        {
            "status": "cooking",
            "timestamp": "2016-01-15"
        },
        {
            "status": "washing ",
            "timestamp": "2014-01-18"
        },
        {
            "status": "enjoying some tea",
            "timestamp": "2014-02-22"
        }
    ],
    "username": "preethiJain"
}
```

Is it possible to write a query in such a way that , it will return the sort the elements of an array based on timestamp and returns the first one from the result .

For example in the above case , it will return me the element

```
{
            "status": "washing ",
            "timestamp": "2014-01-18"
}
```

Currently i am reading the whole structure and sorting it based on programically way and returning the first one , but this is taking a lot of time for processing the request .

Please let me know if this is possible or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Aggregation Framework. The query should be like :

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$match : {"username" : "preethiJain"}},
  {$unwind: "$plans"},
  {$sort: {"plans.timestamp":1}},
  {$limit : 1}
)
```

Comment: hi Thanks for the query , its working fine , can i include username also in that ?? i have tried as $match , but i was unsuccessful , could you please help .

Comment: What you mean by including username? You want to filter data by username?

Comment: Thanks a lot , i am googling this since 2 hours . thanks once again .